# Synchronize two DOM trees in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, merge, sax

I asked this question in a different format and XSLT was mentioned but don't think I explained the solution I need. I have two xml files and using Java and I am trying to write a program that will accept a source and target xml file and for the most part they will have the same structure except the source will have some new elements added and I need to figure out how I can navigate the source DOM and if an element is not found in the target then add it or at this point even just have the program output what elements are not found in the target file making it easier to manually modify the target file. Does anyone know of a utility where I can do something like this and just get a list of elements not found in the target xml file. Am I correct to use a DOM parser vs. SAX. I need help on this, have to write it today and have about 50 xml files to merge!

Am I thinking in line with the idea of navigating the entire source DOM for each node or element get the full path like people/person/john and then on my target DOM somehow test to see if that node exists? Does this sound more like DOM or a SAX parsing paradigm?

Comment: When writing questions, make them as easy to read as possible. That is a big, messy first paragraph you have there.

Comment: if you just need to find differences between two files, what about "diff" (command-line, unix/mac) or graphical diff tools ("meld" or "winmerge"). Assuming your xml is formatted in a similar way, differences will pop out.

Comment: tucuxi, will listen to your feedback for future questions on your first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems like your problem is much simpler then that.

1. parse source into DOM
2. parse dest into DOM
3. traverse source and dest in a depth first search *in parallel*
4. whenever you hit something in source missing in dest, add it (as mentioned in the comments, one easy way to do this is [Document.importNode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29))

Comment: you might also want to mention Document#importNode http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node, boolean)

Comment: Great, I am newbie with DOM can you explain more 3) traverse source and dest in a depth first search parallel. I'm under the gun to get this done if you do contract work I would gladly pay for the code.

Comment: @DuncanKrebs - see [Node.getChildNodes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29)

Comment: Okay, so I need to pony up and figure out the API. Thanks for getting me on the right track, I accepted the answer and upvoted.